# Jackson deserialization for kotlin data classes XML to Kotlin object

Tags: kotlin, jackson, xml-parsing, fasterxml

I have a Kotlin data class like this

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ScoreTiedot", namespace = "http://www.xxxxxx.xxxx.xxx/calculate-score")
data class ScoreTiedot(

    @JsonProperty("MaksukykyLaskelma") val MaksukykyLaskelma: MaksukykyLaskelma,
    @JsonProperty("SovellusTunnus") val SovellusTunnus: String,
    @JsonProperty("Osalliset") val Osalliset: Osalliset,
    @JsonProperty("PankkiNumero") val PankkiNumero: String,
    @JsonProperty("KonttoriNumero") val KonttoriNumero: String,
    @JsonProperty("Hanke") val Hanke: Hanke
)
```

These are some properties and some of them itself composed of Other data classes like (MaksukykyLaskelma or Osallinen). The point here is that although I am using Jackson-dataformatter-xml and jackson-kotlin-module as dependencies it still fails to deserialize with the following exception.

```
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions\n xxx.xxxx.xxx.ScoreTiedot does not have a no-arg default constructor.\n\tthis problem is related to the following location:\n\t\tat xxx.xxxx.xxx..ScoreTiedot\n"
```

It simply asks me to provide the default constructor or in other words default values for all the properties that I don't want to and that's why i am using these dependencies.

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml

My POM dependencies are as follows:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Also in my configuration, i am registering the Kotlin module to XML mapper.

```
  @Bean
    fun xmlMapper(builder: Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder): XmlMapper {
        val mapper: XmlMapper = builder
            .createXmlMapper(true)
            .build()
        mapper.registerKotlinModule()
        return mapper
    }
```